# site css fine in file but compressed in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, compression

im working on a clients site and i made changes to the style.css file in the twentyten theme. file looks fine and normal, but my added style isnt showing up in the chrome inspector when I selet it in the HTML element. So I click on the style.css link in the element inspector to vie the css to see if the class i added is there and everything is compreessed ????

no idea why. there are no caching plugins or anything that I can see.

Anyone have anyida what is happening. Im new to the site and not sure what is going on.

any help appriciated. site is hailprotector.com, so you can see for your self. im stumped.

thanks

UPDATE:

I searched the compressed text and did not find a reference to my new class which is .videostyle

so that file is not MY edited style.css. hmmm....the plot thickens. where is that file and how do I edit it? What hath the other developer done?

Comment: It sounds like there is some sort of build process that you're not using. If that's the case then there will be some sort of source file and then it will be run through the build process to output the compressed code. I'd speak to the other developer to check if this is the case.

Comment: Did you clear your cache when reloading? Your browser may be caching the .css file. (try Ctrl+F5 to reload the page)

Answer (score 0):

It was Cloudflare. A 3rd party that provides all sorts of caching and minifying and DNS or CDN services. Available in most CPANEL's. In the cloud flare settings they had it set to minify JS and CSS. Kinda cool but drove me crazy. I called Bluehost support for VPS and they were awesome and saw that I was using it and that solved all. thanks